straight line intersecting all binormal lines
I'm having trouble with a question involving the binormal lines of the curve $\alpha(t)=(e^{t}\cos t,e^t \sin t,t)$. I computed the binormal vector of the curve, namely $\vec {B}(t)=-(1+e^{2t})^{-1/2}(\cos t,\sin t,-e^t)$, as well as $\vec T(t)$, $\vec N(t)$, $\kappa(t)$ and $\tau(t)$.
The question I can't wrap my head around is the following:

Show that there exists a straight line $r$ of $\mathbb R^3$ that intersects all the binormal lines of $\alpha$.

My first attempt was to set up $r=p+\lambda \vec v$ and try to see if I could compute my way out of $\det(\alpha-p,\vec B,\vec v)=0$ but got nothing.
I started thinking that, maybe, the family of binormal lines would define a plane, so I set up the ruled surface $\phi(t,s)=\alpha(t)+s\vec B(t) $ but I remembered that all points of a ruled surface are hyperbolic so they have non-vanishing gaussian curvature.
Then, here I am, stuck and confused before what seemed to be a silly question at first sight. Any help would be much appreciated.



You remembered incorrectly: Ruled surfaces have $K\le 0$, not $K<0$. Indeed, there are developable (flat) ruled surfaces — namely, cones, cylinders, tangent developables, and planes. Anyhow, it's a nice idea to look at the ruled surface generated by the binormal lines, but it certainly need not be a plane (or, more generally, be flat) in order for the desired result to hold. Indeed, you just want one more line on that ruled surface — one that crosses every ruling.

Just observe that the first two components of $B$ are proportional to $\cos t, \sin t$ at the point with first coordinates also proportional to $\cos t,\sin t$. Therefore the planes through the points of the curve containing the $z$ axis contain the binormals at the corresponding points. Conclusion: all the binormals intersect the $z$ axis.

That was right in front of my eyes and yet I couldn't spot it! Thank you @GReyes!

This exercise can be considered from a different point of view.
The given curve lies on the surface with equation :
$$z=\ln\left(\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}_r\right)$$
This surface is a surface of revolution along Oz (see figure below).
Now, let us remind the result saying that the normal lines to a surface of revolution cross the axis of revolution (see here).
In order to use this result, we must know whether the normals to the surface coincide with the binormals along the curve (which is not the case in general).
Do you see the connection with geodesics ?
Up to you... (another exercise...)
Besides, I think advisable, for many practical differential geometry issues, to use graphical tools that we have at our disposal, in order

to get a concrete understanding of the objects we are working on (for example materialize the ruled surface generated by the binormals),

to help to build conjectures, etc.



Fig. 1: Representation of the part $(x>0,y>0$ of the surface with equation with the curve and its binormals.
Remark about software tools available on-line. One of them I advise  is SAGE (the program below has generated the figure). Just type https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ ; an editor window opens ; copy paste for example this program, then hit button "evaluate".
 var('x y z t')
 from sage.plot.plot3d.shapes import LineSegment
 L=5
 g=implicit_plot3d(z-ln(sqrt(x^2+y^2)),(x,0.1,L),(y,0.1,L),(z,-1,L))
 g+=parametric_plot3d((exp(t)*cos(t),exp(t)*sin(t),t),(t,0,pi/2),color='red',thickness=5)
 g+=LineSegment((0,0,0),(L,0,0),3,color='green') # x-axis
 g+=LineSegment((0,0,0),(0,L,0),3,color='green')
 g+=LineSegment((0,0,0),(0,0,L),3,color='green')
 for k in range(30) :
    t=k/20;
    P=(exp(t)*cos(t),exp(t)*sin(t),t)
    #f=-6/sqrt(1+exp(2*t))
    f=-2
    Q=(exp(t)*cos(t)+f*cos(t),exp(t)*sin(t)+f*sin(t),t-f*exp(t))
    g+=LineSegment(P,Q,0.2,color='black')
 show(g)

